# How can I select all elements after a particular element with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to acces to all elements after certain element to change some attributes. I know there is nextAll() but I can't use jquery.

[image: i need to erase first answer and answer 2 to be updated to 1]

Specifically I need to change the label text and the name attribute from the input.

```
<div class="row respuesta">
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label>Respuesta 1:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" name="respuesta1" onblur="comprobarInputVacio(event)" type="text"/>
      <span class="input-group-btn"></span>
      <span class="input-group-btn"></span>
      <span class="input-group-btn"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row respuesta">
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label>Respuesta 2:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" name="respuesta2" onblur="comprobarInputVacio(event)" type="text"/>
      <span class="input-group-btn"></span>
      <span class="input-group-btn"></span>
      <span class="input-group-btn"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row respuesta">
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label>Respuesta 3:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" name="respuesta3" onblur="comprobarInputVacio(event)" type="text"/>
      <span class="input-group-btn"></span>
      <span class="input-group-btn"></span>
      <span class="input-group-btn"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: best idea yet has been adding all elements after certain element recursively by .nextSibling in an array

Comment: Can you not use `.querySelectorAll()` and only take the elements in the resulting `NodeList` after the element in question?

Comment: queryselector yes. how would that be?

Comment: Well, we haven't seen any of your code, so I would have no idea what selectors to use, nor how to target the element you want as your starting point.

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML so we can understand what you mean with *all elements after element*. Also how do you identify the element after which to select the rest ?

Comment: Flagged as unclear! Create a complete question!

Comment: I cant post HTML other way than with a picture, as it is created with javascript, so I have nowhere to copy it from (neither from inspect element, as i can only drag code).

Comment: @mge also to avoid this being a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) what do you wan to change to the elements ? Because if the problem is the numbering you can use alternative ways that do not require any JS

Comment: I have edited the question so that it is more clear.

Comment: @mge I have updated my answer. See if that is what you're looking for

Comment: "*Specifically I need to change the label text and the name attribute from the input*" - change the label text, and name attribute (of which element(s), in what way? In response to what?

Answer (score 8):

If you can get the `index` of the element after which to start, you can simply use (*assuming elements are siblings*) the [`general sibling combinator (~)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

```
let index = 3; // somehow get the index
let nextsiblings = document.querySelectorAll(`.common-class:nth-child(${index}) ~ *`)
```

same way if you can exactly identify the element with a css selector (*other than index*)

```
let initialSelector= '#id'; // could also be a unique class like .active
let nextsiblings = document.querySelectorAll(`${initialSelector} ~ *`);
```

---

Adding another one where you only have a reference to the node after which to start.

```
// node is the one after which to start
let siblingsAndSelf = Array.from(node.parentNode.children);
let index = siblingsAndSelf.indexOf(node);
let nextAll = siblingsAndSelf.slice(index+1);
```

Comment: Assuming elements are siblings is quite a big assumption.

Comment: @mhodges i based it on the OP comment that his best idea so far is to use `.nextSibling`, and the fact that in the question they mention that they can do it with jquery's `nextAll()` method.

Comment: That's true, fair enough

Comment: Added OP's code if you want to verify this solution works

Comment: The last example was so much useful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this code you have provided, this may help point you in the right direction.

This function takes:

1. A collection of elements
2. A single element as a starting point, from which all subsequent elements will be operated on
3. A callback function that can do whatever you want to do to the elements that are after the element you pass in as the 2nd argument.

```js
var containers = document.querySelectorAll(".respuesta");

var response2Container = Array.prototype.find.call(containers, function (container) {
  return container.querySelector("input[name='respuesta2']") !== null;
});


function applyAfterElement(elems, afterElem, fn) {
  var after = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    let elem = elems[i];
    if (after) {
      fn(elem, i);
    }
    else if (elem === afterElem) {
      after = true;
    }
  }
}

applyAfterElement(containers, response2Container, function (elem, orgIndex) {
  var label = elem.querySelector("label");
  var input = elem.querySelector("input");
  label.innerText = "Updated Respuesta Label:";
  input.setAttribute("name", "updated" + input.name);
});
```

```html
<div class="row respuesta">
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label>Respuesta 1:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" name="respuesta1" onblur="comprobarInputVacio(event)" type="text" />
      <span class="input-group-btn"></span>
      <span class="input-group-btn"></span>
      <span class="input-group-btn"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row respuesta">
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label>Respuesta 2:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" name="respuesta2" onblur="comprobarInputVacio(event)" type="text" />
      <span class="input-group-btn"></span>
      <span class="input-group-btn"></span>
      <span class="input-group-btn"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row respuesta">
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label>Respuesta 3:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" name="respuesta3" onblur="comprobarInputVacio(event)" type="text" />
      <span class="input-group-btn"></span>
      <span class="input-group-btn"></span>
      <span class="input-group-btn"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row respuesta">
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label>Respuesta 4:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" name="respuesta4" onblur="comprobarInputVacio(event)" type="text" />
      <span class="input-group-btn"></span>
      <span class="input-group-btn"></span>
      <span class="input-group-btn"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks good but I don't understant too much the first two functions sorry.

Comment: @mge "I don't understand too much the first two functions". Can you explain exactly which functions you are referring to? And exactly what you don't understand about them? We are trying so hard to help you, but we are getting almost no information/feedback/explanation.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I have finally done, even looking a bit dirty. (cant indent correctly that element indented wrong)

```
function borrarUnaRespuesta(event){
   numRes--;
   var aBorrar = event.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
   var proximoLabel = aBorrar.firstChild.firstChild.textContent;
   var proximoNameAtt = aBorrar.firstChild.firstChild.nextSibling.firstChild.getAttribute("name");
   var elementoPosterior = aBorrar.nextSibling;
   aBorrar.parentNode.removeChild(aBorrar);
   recolocarRespuestas(elementoPosterior,proximoLabel,proximoNameAtt);
}
//coloco bien las respuestas despues de borrar una en concreto
function recolocarRespuestas(elementoPosterior,proximoLabel,proximoNameAtt){
   var anteriorLabel = "";
   var anteriorNameAtt = "";
   while(elementoPosterior.nodeName != "INPUT"){
       anteriorLabel = elementoPosterior.firstChild.firstChild.textContent;
       elementoPosterior.firstChild.firstChild.textContent = proximoLabel;
       anteriorNameAtt = elementoPosterior.firstChild.firstChild.nextSibling.firstChild.getAttribute("name");
elementoPosterior.firstChild.firstChild.nextSibling.firstChild.setAttribute("name",proximoNameAtt);
       proximoNameAtt = anteriorNameAtt;
       proximoLabel = anteriorLabel;
       elementoPosterior = elementoPosterior.nextSibling;
   }
   //this just places correctly the answers
   checkNumRespuestas();
}
```